# Pressing brake pedal during vehicle operation feels "choppy" ?

Tags: brakes

I am driving a 2004 Chevy Impala. When coming to a stop, I press the brake pedal, and I can feel the choppy vibration on the pedal. It's same regardless of weather. Should I get this checked out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes your brake rotors are out of round. You can resurface them as long as they are not too thin.

[image]
The rotor varies in thickness and as it turns when the brakes are applied causes the car to vibrate, and or pulse the brake petal.

It's not an emergency unless it's shaking the car or steering wheel a lot when you brake. I would put a priority on getting it repaired because it will get worse.

More information here [Excessive lateral run-out (warping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_brake#Excessive_lateral_run-out_.28warping.29)

Comment: Is this an urgent issue? What rotors are you talking about?

Comment: @kim jong edited the question let me know if you need more infomation

Comment: I always thought that resurfacing was kind of a bad deal since the difference in cost of resurfacing vs replacement never seemed that high. I guess it depends on the cost of the replacement part though.

Comment: @greg Cost of the rotor is a factor, as well as the cost of resurfacing. One of the shops her will do it for $10 a rotor if you take them the rotors already off the car. Some of the repair shops are going to add between 0.8 and 1.5 hours labor to resurface the rotors even at $50 hour that's expensive. You can always negotiate the price with the repair facility. They make more money resurfacing than by selling you a part. So it's in their best interest to give you a discount on the resurface then to put new rotors on.

Comment: @Larry: Aha, I never thought about taking the rotor off and taking it to the shop.  That's a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I had 2 rotors for my 1991 Caprice Classic turned for about $10 at Pep Boys back in 2001. (I carried both rotors in and carried them out. I was replacing the brake pads myself, as well as a balljoint, so that made it a no-brainer).

Comment: Also, note that some rotors are not thick enough to be turned.

Comment: You should definitely get it fixed. Having the brakes jerk the steering and suspension around can eventually damage things, making the repairs much more expensive than just rotors + pads.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the rotors turned (machined) or simply replace them with new ones.

Comment: Again, why would this be the issue and why would they need to replace anything? Flesh it out.